# how to let a non privelegde user run a program requiring root permsiossions, with out password?

Tags: permissions

I have a program I wrote and it accesses hardware (device files) and requires root permissions to run. I would like this program to be executable by a non privileged user, without the necessity for a root password. I have tried modifying the permissions with `sudo chmod u+s programName` reboot, but the program then the program wont run with `sudo ./programName`

I can remember doing this, like 12 years ago, but I cant figure it out now. Any tips?

Comment: Read `man sudoers visudo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the owner of your program's executable file to `root` with

```
sudo chown root /path/to/program/executable
```

and then set its setuid bit with

```
sudo chmod u+s /path/to/program/executable
```

then you neither need to reboot afterwards nor use `sudo`. Starting the program normally by name will execute it with root privileges. This will however allow *any* user to run the program with root privileges, so you should be *very* sure you programmed it in such a way it cannot be abused to perform other actions than you intended with root privileges.

The first step is essential. The function of the the setuid bit is to cause the program to run with the UID of the file owner. If that owner is not `root` then the program will not have root privileges, even if you run it with `sudo`, since the setuid bit overrides the effect of `sudo`.

So *either* run your program with `sudo` *or* set the setuid bit with `chmod u+s`, but not both.

NB: Instead of running your program with root privilege, it might be better to set the permissions of the device files it accesses to allow the regular user running it the necessary access.

Comment: sweet, that works. I realize the security implications, but the device is a knob. IDK, maybe it could be hacked, but I think it'll be safe for what I'm doing. the web server its on is a more likely target, but its not on the internet. I appreciate the help.